# How to update the Facebook profile picture from iPhone?

Tags: facebook, iphone

How can I change my Facebook profile picture through the iPhone? Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because nowadays questions about using mobile apps are off-topic. Questions about apps for iOS might be on-topic in [apple.se].

Answer (score 5):

**May 13 2013 `>>` Version 6.1**

Tapping your profile picture brings up the option

[image: Tap profile]

Then Choose From Library or Take Photo

or go to a photo on Facebook and select the more `***` icon

[image: Select more]

And you should receive the option there as well

[image: Make Profile Picture]

---

**Feb 22 2013 `>>` Version 5.5**

Facebook has seemed to have removed the option to upload to the Profile Pictures album.

So you will have to either upload to an album or the Mobile Uploads album then "Make Profile Picture" from there.

[image: Albums]

[image: Photos]

[image: Make Profile Picture]

**2011 and before**

Select Photos.
Select the "Profile Pictures" Album.
Click the camera icon in the top right.
Take a photo or choose from library.
Make Profile Picture.

Answer (score 2):

Simply press and hold or long press the picture you want to make as your profile pic and voila! The option to "make profile picture" will come out.

Answer (score 2):

You CAN update from iPad/iPhone   Press and hold the picture when it's full screen and your options come up to make it your profile picture.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be possible in the "Touch site".

Although, when you go to the "Mobile site" (http://m.facebook.com), there seems to be an option to "Make Profile Picture" whenever you're looking at a photo.

Answer (score 1):

You can! Just simply find the picture you would like to be your profile picture, make it full size and hold your finger down on the picture the options will come up to Delete; Save or make it your profile picture! Click make it your profile picture and there you go!!